# Accessing this object of a callback function from outside

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, mocha.js, chai

It might be a bit confusing what I'm asking but I'll try to be as clear as I can.

Basically I'm doing unit test with mocha/chai for my Data Access Layer of my Node.JS server. I'm using bluebird to return a promise and an SQLite Databases.

That's my function insert I want to test :

```
insert(sqlRequest, sqlParams, sqlRequest2) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            let insertStatement = this.getDatabase().prepare(sqlRequest);
            let getStatement = this.getDatabase().prepare(sqlRequest2);

            insertStatement.run(sqlParams, err => {
                console.log('this.changes = ', this.changes);
                if (this.changes === 1) {
                    getStatement.all({ $id: this.lastID }, (err, rows) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('entered second err');
                            reject(err);
                        } else {
                            resolve(rows[0]);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('entered first err ');
                    reject(err);
                }

            });
        }.bind(this));
    }
```

And that's my test with mocha :

```
it('insert : Error 2st SQL query', function (done) {

    const daoCommon = new DaoCommon();
    daoCommon.getDatabase = () => {
      return {
        prepare: (sqlRequest) => {
          return {
            all: (sql, callback) => {
              let err = {};
              let rows = null;
              callback(err, rows);
            },
            run: (sqlParams, callback) => {
              let err = undefined;
              callback(err);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    daoCommon.insert('', '', '')
      .then(success => {
        expect.fail();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        expect(error).to.eql({});
      })
      .finally(function () {
        done();
      })
  });
```

I want to simulate a test where the `this.changes` is equal to 1 but I don't know how/where I can set this value. According to what I've read this `this object` is from the callback function, but I have no idea exactly from where it comes or how to set it for my tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
You can set the `this` of a function you are calling with `.call` of the method.
In your case calling `callback` with `this.changes` value will look like:

```
var thisObject = {
   changes: 1
};
callback.call(thisObject, err);
```

This will set the value `this.changes` of your callback function.

---

The value of `this` is explained in the [API documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback)

> If execution was successful, the `this` object will contain two
>   properties named `lastID` and `changes` which contain the value of the
>   last inserted row ID and the number of rows affected by this query
>   respectively.

It means that the `callback` function will always have `this.changes`. You can not change it unless you set `this.changes = something` manually, which I don't understand why would you do that.

Comment: I want to do that in my test as I show above to simulate the case when the changes = 1. In my test I'm not using a DB I'm creating my object to simulate cases like you can see in the mocha function.

Comment: You can set `this` when calling the function `callback(err)` by using `.call()`. eg: `callback.call({changes:1}, err)`. this will set `changes` to `1`.

Comment: thanks sir it was exactly what I was looking for, worked like a charm.

Comment: I updated, and pls accept the answer to help others find.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for @Maxali comment, I will post the answer below :

> You can set this when calling the function callback(err) by using .call(). eg: callback.call({changes:1}, err). this will set changes to 1

And note that I had to change this line `insertStatement.run(sqlParams, err => {` where I have the callback from an arrow function to a function declaration `insertStatement.run(sqlParams, function(err) {` for this to work. I assume this is due to the this which in an arrow function doesn't refer to the object inside the function itself.